# Python - import check error

Tags: python, import

I am trying to,

```
import check
```

but I am the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <fragment>
ImportError: No module named check
```

I am using Python 2.6.6 and this module should be included.
How can I fix this?

Comment: why do you think check is an included module?  Im pretty sure its not ... and I have never heard of it ...

Comment: Is `check` a module you have written?

Comment: @karthikr I think here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/check/0.3.2

Answer (score 0):

try

```
C:\>  easy_install check
```

I have never used this module or heard of it ... and it is definitely not a builtin module (in 2.6.6 at least)

see also
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/check/0.3.2

Comment: Was not helpful. This module is indeed included in Python 2.6.6

Comment: @user3058606 in an argument between you and Joran Beasley about Python, you lose. Sorry.

Comment: @user3058606 Can you point out where in [python 2.6's standard library](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/index.html) is that module? I don't see it, and hence I believe you have to install it. Either using `easy_install` or `pip` or the package manager of your OS, or from source or in any other way.

Comment: Definitely not in the definitive Standard library list : https://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/index.html